# How to show and use textformfield under each post in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Posts screen where list of posts are displayed. I want to add a textformfield at the bottom area of each post so that users can enter their comments on particular post. As we know that we cannot create a TextEditingController for multiple textformfields.

How can I create, show and use textformfield with the each post for entering users comments?

Comment: OK, you've figured out how the editing controls work. Please stop ping-ponging the contents of this question back and forth. Decide what you want it to look like, and then *leave it there*.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are multiple ways to do this, but here is one fairly simple approach.

Create a `Map` where the key is a TextFormField and the value is a TextEditingController.

`Map<TextFormField, TextEditingController> fields = new Map<TextFormField, TextEditingController>();`

Create a new controller and text field for each post and add them to the Map.

`fields[text] = controller;`

When you want to get the values, you can pass the text field into a method that gets the controller for that field from the Map.

Here is a very basic example of how this can work:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DynamicTextFieldsWithControllers extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => DynamicTextFieldsWithControllersState();
}

class DynamicTextFieldsWithControllersState extends State<DynamicTextFieldsWithControllers> {

  Map<TextFormField, TextEditingController> fields = new Map<TextFormField, TextEditingController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
      TextFormField text = TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
      );
      fields[text] = controller;
      widgets.add(Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 15.0),
        child: Column(children: [
          text,
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text("Submit", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed: () {
              getTextValue(text);
            },
          )
        ],)
      ));
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: widgets),
    );
  }

  getTextValue(TextFormField text) {
    TextEditingController controller = fields[text];
    String value = controller.text;
    print(value);
    return value;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @daddygames for your interest, I will try it today in the night. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kamlesh If this post was helpful in answering your question, please mark it as an answer. Thanks and happy coding!