# using TextFormField in a table (DataTable)

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, provider, textformfield

i have a table that has a structure of the following

```
             DataTable2(
                    columnSpacing: 15,
                    showCheckboxColumn: true,
                    headingTextStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    columns: [
                      //list of columns
                    ],
                    rows: mainScheduleModel
                        .map((data) =>
                            DataRow(
                                cells: [
                                  //list of rows
                                ]))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
```

and in the list of rows, i used a TextFormField to show my data. here is one sample DataCell from the row.

```
           DataCell(
                TextFormField(
                    initialValue: data.boardingDate,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: data.boardingDate
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    readOnly: true,
                    onTap: (){
                     _pickDateDialog();
                                  },
                        onFieldSubmitted: (val) {
                                    data.boardingDate = val;
                                    Provider.of<SchedulesProvider>(
                                        context,
                                        listen: false)
                                        .editData(data);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
```

and when that row is clicked a showDatePicker dialog shows up. here is the function to select date

```
  void _pickDateDialog() {
    showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(1950),
        lastDate: DateTime
            .now())
        .then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        //for rebuilding the ui
        _selectedDate = pickedDate;
      });
    });
  }
```

my question is, how can i set the value of the TextFormField according to the selected date..

i cant use controller because it sets the values of all the DataCells of that Column to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html). Create one in the widget where your TextFormField exists, then assign it as the controller for the text control.

```
// create a controller for the input
TextEditingController boardingDateController = new TextEditingController();

DataCell(
    TextFormField(
            initialValue: data.boardingDate,
            controller: boardingDateController, // <- assign controller here
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: data.boardingDate
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            readOnly: true,
            onTap: (){
             _pickDateDialog();
            },
                    
    );
)
```

When you setState in the date picker, you then test the "text" property of the controller, which will then update the value inside the input.

```
void _pickDateDialog() {
    showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            initialDate: DateTime.now(),
            firstDate: DateTime(1950),
            lastDate: DateTime
                    .now())
            .then((pickedDate) {
        if (pickedDate == null) {
            return;
        }
        setState(() {
            //for rebuilding the ui
            _selectedDate = pickedDate;
            boardingDateController.text = _selectedDate; // update the input value here
        });
    });
}
```

If you are dynamically creating rows and are not sure how many controllers you will need, then you may look at my answer to a similar question here => [How to show and use textformfield under each post in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67904973/how-to-show-and-use-textformfield-under-each-post-in-flutter/67905363#67905363)

Comment: thank you for your reply, i did the way you told me.. created the Map.. but still the textformfield is not updating according to the selected date.
idk what im doing wrong, is the controller attribute in the TextFormField written like this?                                 

controller: fields[data],

Comment: `fields[data]` looks incorrect. Hard to tell without seeing your adjusted code. For each cell that contains the textbox, you create a controller, assign it to the textbox control and then use the textbox control as the Key and the controller as the Value of the Map item. You can see I do that in the `for(int i...)` loop in the other post.